# How do I change test stub framework?

Tags: testdriven.net, coderush

When I stub out a test with CodeRush, it is automatically inserting a using statement for NUnit when I already have a using statement for MBUnit.  Is there a way to change the default test framework used when using the templates?  I was unable to find it if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the templates you can change the default test namespace used.  You can also add conditional logic to check if the project references MBunit.Framework, if so add the MBUnit.Framework using statement, else use Nunit.